# Admin dashboard Most Viewed Products Tab statistics not updating

Tags: magento2, dashboard

**Most Viewed Products** tab records not being updating while visit to many products with guest user or even registered user.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to refresh the statistics, they are not updated in real-time as that would slow the site down. From admin panel, go to Reports > Refresh Statistics. Select 'Most Viewed' from the grid and select 'Refresh Lifetime Statistics' from the actions drop down.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to refresh the statistics  From admin panel, go to Reports > Refresh Statistics, so  I make  your follow ". Select 'Most Viewed' from the grid and select 'Refresh Lifetime Statistics' from the actions drop down." , so  the tab "Most View Products" still records not being updating....

Comment: my version Magento CE 2.1.2